# Zimra - How I can handle  HTML forms in zimlets?

Tags: html, ajax, forms, handle, zimbra

I try to create a tab Zimlet that contains a HTML form. I just want to now how I can handle submit button in my form or how can I submit a form with ajax toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Let me have a general suggestion...

> Try to do everything base on zimbra standards

You can check and download examples to be familiar with the default way to do the different jobs...

Back to your question, how is your form made? is it a normal html form or created dynamically by javascript?

If html, just set the onclick of your submit form to the zimlet's function and define whatever you wanna do inside that function

```
   <input onClick="yourzimlet.prototype.OkFunction();" type="button" >


   yourzimlet.prototype.OkFunction= function(){
     //do somthing...
   }
```

if in javascript, you have (at-least) two ways

1-using normal onclick

```
var formTag = document.createElement("form");
    //add form elements to formTag... 

var inputTag = document.createElement("input");
inputTag.type= 'button';
inputTag.setAttribute("value", "submit ... ");
inputTag.onclick = function() { yourzimlet.prototype.OkFunction();}
formTag.appendChild(inputTag);

   yourzimlet.prototype.OkFunction= function(){
     //do somthing...
   }
```

2-using zimbra javascript API

Instead of having a form with normal onclick, better (depends on your situation) to create a form dynamically using javascript and add a dwtButton as submit button

http://files.zimbra.com/docs/zimlet/zcs/7.2.0/jsdocs/symbols/DwtButton.html

You can define a listener for the form's submit button and then do whatever you want to do in your listener function

In all conditions you can have access to the form's elements and their values by their id